# Accessing Parse Server on Google Cloud using Parse Dashboard.

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, heroku, google-cloud-platform, parse-server

I'm fairly new to server related stuff and I have a few questions to ask regarding the use of Parse dashboard on Parse Server deployed on Google Cloud.

Previously, I managed to deploy my parse server to Heroku.com and also manage to access my Parse Server through the Parse Dashboard via the Environment Variables set in Heroku console (after successful deployment to Heroku).

However, I'm now trying to use Google Cloud as my service to deploy my parse server.

I followed the tutorials stated here:

https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/resources/frameworks/parse-server

And successfully "deployed parse server" to gcloud. The thing is, there are no "Environment Variables" to set so that I could access it via the Parse Dashboard command:

parse-dashboard --appId myaddid --masterkey mymasterkey --...

Do enlighten me as I'm just a beginner at this. 
Thanks!

Comment: I am now looking into the same thing. Did you find any solutions?